# When moving layer labels they stick together

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling

in my qgis project i have a layer with multiple points. I labelled all of these points different and suddenly when i move the layers they "connect" all on the same spot and i cant split them back or move one of them at a time. They seem to be stuck together.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

I am using QGIS 3.10.12

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to choose a **unique key**. The window for this pops up the first time you move a label:

[image]

You cannot use an expression here. So in case you do not have one, you need to add it to the layer first. You can do this via field calculator and use the expression `$id`.

To reset the auxiliary storage (and the chosen key as well as label positions) go to layer properties -> auxiliary storage -> auxiliary layer -> delete

[image]

unfortunately you cannot remove only the key afterwards, so you need to reposition your labels again.